# sidekiq method to store some data in sqlite3 database, rather than redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sidekiq

I am currently working on a rails project, i was asked to save progress of a sidekiq workers and store it, so the user who is using the application can see the progress. Now i am faced with this dilemna, is it better to just write out to a text file or save it in a database.

If it is a database, then how to save it in a model object. I know we can store the progress of workers by just sending out the info to log file.

class YourWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker

```
  def perform
  logger.info { "Things are happening." }
  logger.debug { "Here's some info: #{hash.inspect}" }
  end
```

So if i want to save the progress of workers in a data model, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Job` class and then update some attribute of the currently working job.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assume that there is a 'status' attribute that is defined as 'text'
end
```

Then when you queue something to happen you create a new `Job` and pass the `id` of the `Job` to `perform` or `perform_async`.

```
job = Job.create!
YourWorker.perform_async job.id
```

Then in your worker, you'd receive the id of the job to be worked on, and then retrieve and update that record.

```
def perform(job_id)
  job = Job.find job_id
  job.status = "It's happening!"
  job.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your thread title says that the data is unstructured, but your problem description indicates that the data should be structured. Which is it? Speed is not always the most important consideration, and it doesn't seem to be very important in your case. The most important consideration is how your data will be used. Will the way your data is used in the future change? Usually, a database with an appropriate model is the better answer because it allows flexibility for future requirements. It also allows other clients access to your data.